# Backwards compatibility with method parameter changes

Tags: java, spring

I have the following method (1):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/comments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Comment save(@RequestBody Comment comment) throws UnauthorisedException {
    ...
}
```

that needs to be changed to (2):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/comments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public HttpEntity<Comment> save(@RequestParam(value = "comment", required = false) String comment,
                    @RequestParam("id") String id,
                    @RequestParam(value = "attachment", required = false) MultipartFile attachment,
                    @RequestParam(value = "attachmentThumbnail", required = false) MultipartFile attachmentThumbnail,
                    @RequestParam(value = "attachmentType", required = false) MediaType attachmentType) throws UnauthorisedException {
    ...
}
```

However, changing the `save` method to this is a breaking change from the previous version. How can I make sure `/comments` will work in both `(1)` and `(2)`? I could add a version number in front of the mapping e.g. `/v2/comment` but this will quickly produce lots and lots of unnecessary code.

The `Comment` class looks like this:

```
@Document
public class Comment {

    @NotNull
    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    private Date timestamp;

    @NotNull
    private String comment;

    @NotNull
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnore
    private String idOfUser;

    // Optional Attachment variables
    private MediaType commentAttachmentType;
    private CommentFile commentAttachmentVideo;
    private CommentFile commentAttachmentVideoThumbnail;

    private CommentFile commentAttachmentImage;
    private CommentFile commentAttachmentImageThumbnail;

    public Comment() {
        setTimestamp(new Date());
    }

    // Getters and setters for each variable
}
```

Comment: make 2 method and call from other?

Comment: @ColdFire what do you mean?

Comment: It probably would help if you added the code for the `Comment` class to your question.

Comment: @VGR done. The problem is my client previously sent the parameters JSON encoded in the request body, but now I have to send them URL encoded as request parameters.